# C# Linq can't format output list in the order I need for JSON result

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json, linq

I encountered problem when formating my object to serialise for Json.

my model:

```
    [Table("Stores")]
public class DeliveryPoint
{
    [Key]
    public Guid StoreId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [StringLength(20)]
    [Display(Name = "Store name")]
    public string StoreName { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Location> Location { get; set; }
    public virtual Company Company { get; set; }
    public List<DeliveryCost> DeliveryPrice{ get; set; }
}

[Table("Drop_Prices")]
public class DeliveryCost
{
    [Key]
    public Int16 id { get; set; }
    public virtual DeliveryPoint Store { get; set; }
    public virtual Location DC { get; set; }
    public double Cost { get; set; }
}
```

my controller

```
        public JsonResult GetAllStores()
    {

        var stores = _db.Stores.Select(d => new MyClass
            {
                name = d.StoreName,
                cost = d.DeliveryPrice.ToDictionary( item => item.DC.LocationID,item=> item.Cost)
            }).ToList();


        return Json(stores, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }

    public class MyClass
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public Dictionary<Guid,double> cost { get; set; }
    }
```

I desired Output would be

```
[{"name":"foo","cost":{"82ec8689-d9e3-49e6-ba12-af091ac42760":"400"}}]
```

So the proble is I get error sometimes is circular error or LINQ

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.Guid,System.Double] ToDictionary[DeliveryCost,Guid,Double]

Comment: It might be because of this line: d.DeliveryPrice.ToDictionary( item => item.DC.LocationID,item=> item.Cost), did you check this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25923721/linq-to-entities-does-not-recognize-the-method-system-collections-generic-dicti

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that LINQ to Entities can't convert your expression to SQL.  Not every C# expression tree can be converted to SQL, only a limited set of operations are supported.

You can always get around this kind of issue by materializing the entities in memory and doing the transform in memory. So query the database for the entities you need, and pull them into memory with a `.ToList()` and then do the work on them to shape them into the desired JSON.

Whether this is efficient depends very much on the specifics of the situation. It may be less efficient, or it could in fact be more efficient than doing the equivalent work in SQL. All you can do is try it out and see.

Comment: thanks for you answer, However I get `A circular reference was detected while serializing an object of type ` when using .ToList()

Comment: Is that a different error message? The one in the question is 'LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method....'?  Are you getting 2 different error messages?  If you're getting that kind of error it suggests something wrong with the model or the data - but that's hard to tell from the code.  I'd still be tempted to materialize the entities in a simple way first and work on them in memory.  It's probably faster anyway.

Comment: no, this other error comes when I try to use .ToList(), Propably I have models set up badly or something